# consul health check: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul

I'm using spring cloud consul in my application. when I started the application I have no exception (service Registed in consul). but when consul check health I got this error:

```
HTTP GET https://xxxxxxxxxx:8181/health: 503 Service Unavailable Output: {
"status" : "DOWN"
}
```

Here is my configuration file:

```
   spring:
    application:
      name: @pom.artifactId@
    cloud:
     config:
       enabled: false

   consul:
     config:
       enabled: true
        host: localhost
        port: 8500
     discovery:
        scheme: https

  endpoints:
   health:
    sensitive: false
   restart:
     enabled: true
   shutdown:
     enabled: true
```

my pom is as follow:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your configuration is a little bit incorrect.
The latest [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/spring-cloud-consul.html) contains the following configuration example:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
```

***BTW***: The latest `spring-cloud-consul` version is `RC1`